# Can someone tell me the file format of SQL Server files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

SQL Server files - what format are they, can't recall?

Comment: mdf, but you aren't supposed to read them directly.

Comment: Mdf or ndf for data, ldf for logs...don't touch those, you might corrupt them

Comment: @SQLMenace haha, I always mount them!

Comment: well you can attach them by using sp_attach_db

Answer (score 2):

Erm, MDF for data storage and LDF for logs but those are proprietary file formats which you are not supposed to manipulate directly.

Answer (score 2):

The book "[Inside Microsoft® SQL Server(TM) 2005: The Storage Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621055)" describes in detail the format of these files.

Paul Randal has also lots of information on his blog. 
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/